# How to detect all touch and non touch screen devices in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a possible way of adding to the script below so it will detect all touch screen phones and all non touch screen phones?

```
  // Checks the users device and if a mobile device, it redirects them too the mobile version of our site
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

    if ($berry == true)
    { 
    header('Location: http://mobile.example.co/');
    }elseif($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod == true){
    header('Location: http://touch.example.co/');
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-php.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a PHP problem ;)

There is no easy solution sadly, but you can have a look at this : http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/.
It's a database of user agents and their properties. It should have a field for touch screen inside.